# no console output with slf4j logger

Tags: java, slf4j

I have controller class(in my maven project) in my app and there  I have the following import statements defined( I have recently started looking at it so don't know what previous person has done regarding any changes related to logs):

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
```

And wheneever I have used something like

`logger.info("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");`

I have seen the results getting printed on the console.

However, there is one maven dependency that I am using and I am using the exact same imports in one of the java file inside that maven dependency as mentioned above, but for some reason nothing is getting printed 
on the console when I try to print anything like the following:

```
logger.info("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
```

Is there any configuration setting I need to do for printing on the console?

Comment: I think there should be some configuration files for the logger(some `.properties` or `.xml` file). please check the `resources` directory of the project

Comment: slf4j is a facade, what implementation are you using, logback?  For an explanation, read: https://www.slf4j.org/

Comment: Inside `resources` I have `application.properties` file where I noticed the following line

`logging.level.com.abc.mypackage.employee=DEBUG
env=DEV
email_to=email@example.com`
Not sure how to figure out how to check what implementation I am using. Reading the documentation mentioned above. I tried putting my email above but I didn't get any logs via email. I do see `logback-classic-1.1.5.jar` which I believe says that I am using logback implementation

Comment: Hey all, I am wondering even if logger isn't working a simple `System.out.println("Test");` should output on console in case of dependency, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding logevents to dependencies in the .pom-file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.logevents</groupId>
    <artifactId>logevents</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.6</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```